# Using USD dollars in taxi in Canada

Tags: canada, money, taxis, payment

Is a taxi in a major city in Canada (Ottawa, Vancouver, and such) likely to accept United States dollars ([USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar)) in cash as payment?

Comment: Probably, at a crap exchange rate such as par,  but I suggest using a credit card. Or ask the cabbie to take you to an ATM and wait. It's not legal tender and they are not a bank or currency exchange.

Comment: Use an Uber instead.

Answer (score 2):

In Vancouver: yes. However, currently this is a very bad deal because the cabbie will offer a 1:1 exchange rate so you are paying 20% more. Source: personal experience.

Comment: Well that solves the issue of a tip as well. ;-)

Comment: Note: Vancouver is a border city while Ottawa is not. This answer might or might be applicable in Ottawa. I do not know.